# Переход по URL в браузере

Tags: http, https, браузер, webbrowser

Что происходит после вставки URL в адресную строку браузера и нажатия на Enter ? Вопрос с собеседования на позицию Software Developer

Comment: происходит магия!!! (рекомендуется к просмотру клип бочарика про мобильные телефоны на борту самолёта).

Answer (score 0):

Это смешно, но на недавнем собеседовании я отвечал на этот вопрос.

Сначала я уточнил, что рассказывать о том, как там проходят сигналы по дорожкам клавиатуры, преобразуются в коды и приходят по USB - не надо, достаточно описать всё, относящееся к браузеру.

Потом я уточнил, надо ли рассказывать про уровень DNS и локальный DNS - кеш. Не надо было.

В результате я стал рассказывать о HTTP - запросах и ответах, HTTP заголовках и т.п.

Ключевыми пунктами рассказа было то, что

1. протокол HTTP 1.0 и 1.1 - очень простой, и запрос (если не переходить на уровень HTTPS) можно набрать вручную и получить ответ прямо через телнет.
2. В современности большую роль играет не только запрос-ответ, но и заголовки браузера.
3. Среди заголовков - тут меня немного направили на нужный путь - в запросе важную роль играет имя хоста, (и это то, чем HTTP 1.1 отличается от HTTP 1.0), а в ответе - MIME - тип, который фактически сообщает браузеру, как нужно интрепертировать тело ответа.

Это - не полный ответ на Ваш вопрос, но на том собеседовании, которе я проходил, в дальнейшие детали меня не попросили углубляться.

А вообще - вопрос довольно популярный, наверняка можно найти и гораздо более полные ответы. Но ключевые моменты, которые я подчеркнул, скорее всего, важны.

Успехов!